# Strict Definition of "Few"

Tags: meaning

I've seen other questions on the usage of "few", but I'm wondering if there is an official definition on the numerical value of the word. The common rule seems to be a couple is two, a few is three or more, and several is something bigger. So is there an official number assigned to the word from some reputable source?

Comment: In a word, no.  There is no one in a position to even make such a rule.

Comment: Less than many Probably but not necessarily less than a moderate number.

Answer (score -1):

1 < few < 7

From here: [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220792)

Comment: Linking to this question doesn't provide an answer. And you give no substantiation for your claim that 1 < few < 7.